# Edit and sanitize user input in a servlet when Code is allowed?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, html-sanitizing

The webpage I'm working on with JSP and a Java Servlet needs to enable the user to write comments and articles which contain text but also Code of various languages (including html and javascript).
The data is stored in a mysql database and displayed later on the page.

For input, I thought to use one of the many WYSIWYG Editors out there.
Those usually produce (x)Html code for the database.

This means I need a type of sanitizing on serverside before inserting into the database since the editor could be easily circumvented and malicious code displayed onto the site (the database itself is secured by prepared statements).

What would be the best and most simple way to approach this topic?

And would it make more sense to switch to BBCode Input instead of html?

I've found several threads here around, but most don't take into account that code actually needs to be displayed on the site and most threads are several years old already.

Huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use KefirBB to use BBCodes or for HTML filtration.
https://github.com/kefirfromperm/kefirbb